# Conditional expectation for maximum function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, markov-chains, conditional-expectation, markov-process

I have a discrete-time Markov chain queuing problem.

Packets (computer packets, that is) arrive in the intervals. $A_n$ denotes the number of arrivals in the interval $(n - 1, n)$, where $n \ge 1$, and the $A_n$ are independent and identically distributed. The probability mass function is $P(A_n = j) = \dfrac{1}{4}$ for $j = 0, 1, 2, 3$.

The packets first enter a buffer that can hold $K = 4$ packets. If the amount of packets arriving is greater than $K = 4$, then any surplus is terminated. One packet is dispatched per unit time (assuming there are packets waiting to be dispatched in the buffer), where unit time is, as I said, $n = 1, 2, \dots$. For time $n$, the packets are dispatched *after* the new entrance of packets $A_n$, but before the arrivals at the next time, $A_{n + 1}$.

$X_n$ is the amount of packets in the buffer at time $n$. This is before any packets have been dispatched. So we have that $X_n$ is a MC and has state space $\{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 \}$. We assume that the queue is empty at the beginning (that is, that $X_0 = 0$).

The $p_{i,j}$ are the elements of the transition matrix $P$.

Let $Y_n$ be the number of packets lost during the $n$th time slot.
So we have that

$$Y_{n + 1} = \begin{cases} \max\{ 0, A_n - K \}, & X_n = 0 \\ \max\{0, X_n - 1 + A_{n + 1} - K\}, & X_n > 0 \end{cases}.$$

I am trying to find $E[Y_{n + 1} \vert X_0 = 0]$.

I do not understand how to do this. Thinking about how conditional expectation is done, my understanding is that the expressions should look something like $E[ A_n - 4 > 0 \vert X_0 = 0 ] P(A_n - 4 > 0 \vert X_0 = 0)$, or something. But, honestly, I have no idea how to do this.

I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to clarify this.

The solution is said to be $\dfrac{1}{4}p^{(n)}_{0, 3} + \dfrac{3}{4}p^{(n)}_{0, 4}$, where $p^{(n)}_{i, j}$ are the values of the $n$th-step transition matrix. It's not so much the solution itself that I'm interested in; rather, I'm interested in the calculations and reasoning that leads to the solution.

---

With regards to the transition matrix, the textbook presents the example as follows:

> Let $A_n$ be the number of packets that arrive at the switch during the $n$th slot. Let $X_n$ be the number of packets in the buffer at the end of the $n$th slot. Now, if $X_n = 0$, then there are no packets available for transmission at the beginning of the $(n + 1)$st slot. Hence all the packets that arrive during that slot, namely $A_{n + 1}$, are in the buffer at the end of that slot unless $A_{n + 1} > K$, in which case the buffer is full at the end of the $(n + 1)$st slot. Hence $X_{n + 1} = \min\{ A_{n + 1}, K \}$. If $X_n > 0$, one packet is removed at the beginning of the $(n + 1)$st slot and $A_{n + 1}$ packets are added during that slot, subject to capacity limitations. Combining these cases, we get
>
> $$X_{n + 1} = \begin{cases} \min\{ A_{n + 1} \}, K & \text{if} \ X_n = 0 \\ \min\{ X_n + A_{n + 1} - 1, K \} & \text{if} \ 0 < X_n \le K. \end{cases}$$
>
> Assume that $\{ A_n, n \ge 1 \}$ is a sequence of iid random variables with common pmf
>
> $$P(A_n = k) = a_k, k \ge 0.$$
>
> Under this assumption, $\{ X_n, n \ge 0 \}$ is a DTMC on state space $\{ 0, 1, 2, \dots, K \}$. The transition probabilities can be computed as follows. For $0 \le j < K$,
>
> $$\begin{align} P(X_{n + 1} = j \vert X_n = 0) &= P(\min\{ X_{n + 1}, K \} = j \vert X_n = 0) \\ &= P(X_{n + 1} = j) \\ &= a_j \end{align}$$
>
> $$\begin{align} P(X_{n + 1} = K \vert X_n = 0) &= P(\min\{ A_{n + 1}, K \} = K \vert X_n = 0) \\ &= P(A_{n + 1} \ge K) \\ &= \sum_{k = K}^\infty a_k. \end{align}$$
>
> Similarly, for $1 \le i \le K$ and $i - 1 \le j < K$,
>
> $$\begin{align} P(X_{n + 1} = j \vert X_n = i) &= P(\min\{ X_n + A_{n + 1} - 1, K \} = j \vert X_n = i) \\ &= P(A_{n + 1} = j - i + 1) \\ &= a_{j - i + 1}. \end{align}$$
>
> Finally, for $1 \le i \le K$,
>
> $$\begin{align} P(X_{n + 1} = K \vert X_n = i) &= P(\min\{ X_n + A_{n + 1} - 1, K \} = K \vert X_n = i) \\ &= P(A_{n + 1} \ge K - i + 1) \\ &= \sum_{k = K - i + 1}^\infty a_k. \end{align}$$
>
> Combining all these cases using the notation
>
> $$b_j = \sum_{k = j}^\infty a_k,$$
>
> we get the transition probability matrix
>
> $$P = \begin{bmatrix} a_0 & a_1 & \dots & a_{K - 1} & b_K \\ a_0 & a_1 & \dots & a_{K - 1} & b_K \\ 0 & a_0 & \dots & a_{K - 2} & b_{K - 1} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & \dots & a_0 & b_1 \end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: How are the $X_n$'s distributed? Do they have any relation to any other variables?

Comment: @DinosaurEgg Please see my edit. Does that clarify?

Comment: Could you check if the solution you wrote is indeed correct? The solution I got has one more term. Thanks

Comment: @DaviBarreira I have copied it correctly, but it is possible that the solution is erroneous. Feel free to post your answer, so that we can all review it and discuss (what could very well be an error in the provided solution).

Comment: Ok. I will revise and post it.

Comment: @DaviBarreira Thank you. It is not uncommon for authors to have incorrect solutions for more-involved problems such as these, so, as I said, that could very well be the case.

Comment: I revised and I got it wrong. I think your solution is indeed correct.

Comment: Unortunately i could not undestrand the sequence of events (dispatcing and entrance) and the instants at which transition probabilities are determined. Anyway, the answer follows from the law of total expectation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So $X_n$ is a Markov chain with state space $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ and $X_0=0$. Let us determine the transition matrix:

When $X_n \leq 1$, then $X_{n+1}=A_{n+1}$, because you dispatch the potential packet in the buffer before getting another one. 
When $X_n \geq 2$, then $X_{n+1} = \min(4,X_n-1+A_{n+1})$.

So, writing everything out, the transition matrix (I'm considering the probability distributions of the $X_k$ as column vectors) is:

$P=\begin{bmatrix}
0.25 & 0.25 & 0    & 0    & 0\\
0.25 & 0.25 & 0.25 & 0    & 0\\
0.25 & 0.25 & 0.25 & 0.25 & 0\\
0.25 & 0.25 & 0.25 & 0.25 & 0.25\\
0    & 0    & 0.25 & 0.5  & 0.75\\
\end{bmatrix}$

Now, depending on the values of $X_n$ and $A_{n+1}$, we split into different cases:

$X_n \leq 2$: $Y_{n+1}=0$ (one packet is dispatched so there remains at most one, and at most three are added so none need to be dismissed)

$X_n = 3$: $Y_{n+1} = 1$ if $A_{n+1}=3$ and $0$ otherwise (explanation is similar to that below)

$X_n = 4$: then we dispatch one packet, (three remain) and add $A_{n+1}$ of them, and dismiss all the packet but four: thus the number of packets dismissed is $0$ if $A_{n+1} \leq 1$, $1$ if $A_{n+1} = 2$, and $2$ if $A_{n+1}=3$.

Having written this all out, we can write:

$\mathbb{E}[Y_{n+1}|X_0=0] = \mathbb{E}[Y_{n+1}1(X_n \geq 3)|X_0=0]$ (as $Y_{n+1}1(X_n \leq 2)=0$) and then split by linearity over the values of $A_{n+1}$ and $X_n$:

$\mathbb{E}[Y_{n+1}|X_0=0]=\mathbb{E}[1(X_n=3,A_n=3)+(A_{n+1}-1)^+1(X_n=4)|X_0=0]$.

Now, $\sigma(A_{n+1})$ and $\sigma(X_0,\ldots,X_n)$ are independent, so by the properties of conditional expectations, $\mathbb{E}[1(X_n=3,A_n=3)|X_0=0] = \mathbb{E}[1(A_n = 3)]\mathbb{E}[1(X_n=3|X_0=0)] = P(A_{n+1} = 3)P(X_n=3|X_0=0)=\frac{1}{4}p^{(n)}_{3,0}$ (I'm using column vectors to be applied to transition matrices, hence possibly the index reversal).

Similarly, $$\mathbb{E}[(A_{n+1}-1)^+1(X_n=4)|X_0=0] = \mathbb{E}[(A_{n+1}-1)^+]\mathbb{E}[1(X_n=4)|X_0=0] = \frac{1}{4}\left((0-1)^++(1-1)^++(2-1)^++(3-1)^+\right)p^{(n)}_{4,0} = \frac{3}{4}p^{(n)}_{4,0},$$ which shows the final formula:

$$\mathbb{E}[Y_{n+1}|X_0=0] = \frac{1}{4}p^{(n)}_{3,0}+\frac{3}{4}p^{(n)}_{4,0},$$ which we wanted to show.

Comment: Ok, I have edited my post with the textbook example of the transition matrix. How is this consistent with the matrix you presented?

Comment: Also, I don't understand your notation. What is meant by $1(X_n \geq 3)$ in  $\mathbb{E}[Y_{n+1}1(X_n \geq 3)|X_0=0]$?

Comment: $1(X_n \geq 3)$ (for instance) is the random variable that is $1$ when $X_n \geq 3$, and $0$ when $X_n < 3$.

Comment: For the transition matrix, mine is the transpose of yours (since $a_j=0.25$, $j < K=4$ and $b_4=0$). Indeed, in your transition matrix $T$, $T_{i,j}=P(X_{n+1}=j|X_n=i)$. In my transition matrix $P$, $P_{i,j}=P(X_{n+1}=i|X_n=j)$.

Comment: Hmm, so how exactly do we calculate what I'm looking for? You wrote that $\mathbb{E}[Y_{n+1}|X_0=0] = \mathbb{E}[Y_{n+1}1(X_n \geq 3)|X_0=0]$, but this just says that $\mathbb{E}[Y_{n+1}|X_0=0] = \mathbb{E}[Y_{n+1}1(X_n \geq 3)|X_0=0] = \mathbb{E}[Y_{n+1}|X_0=0]$ when $X_n \ge 3$. You left out precisely the calculations that interested in, no?

Comment: No: I split $Y_{n+1}$ according to the values of $X_n$. That line just says that we need only consider the terms when $X_n \geq 3$.

Comment: What is $\mathbb{E}[1(X_n=3,A_n=3)+(A_{n+1}-1)^+1(X_n=4)|X_0=0]$ supposed to mean? Is there a typo in here?

Comment: No: that’s just an equivalent expression for $Y_{n+1}$. $1(X_n=3,A_{n+1}=3)$ is $1$ when $X_n=A_{n+1}=3$ and $0$ otherwise. $(A_{n+1}-1)^+1(X_n=4)$ is just a means to have a neat expression for $X_n=4$: no loss if $A_{n+1} \leq 1$, one if $A_{n+1}=2$, two when $A_{n+1}=3$.